# How to access v-model value using parameter in VUE

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to access v-model value using parameter and I try the code below

```
<template>
 <div v-for="(item, idx) in data">
   <input :id="item" :v-model="item"></input>
   <button @click="submitTest(item)"> testbtn </button>
 </div>
</template>

<script setup>
var data = {'test1': 'val1', 'test2': 'val2'}
function submitTest(itemParam){
 alert(itemParam.value)
}
</script>
```

And actually in submitTest function(alert line), it doesn't access to input tag v-model but itemParam(string value itself) value. What I want is to access input 'item value' using parameter that is delivered by  item parameter.

I tried the code above and as a result, it actually access to 'itemParam' string value itself not delivered parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing your data - this works

> NOTE: you can also use `reactive` instead of `ref`

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const data = ref({'test1': 'val1', 'test2': 'val2'})
function submitTest(key){
 alert(key)
}
</script>

<template>
<div v-for="(value, key) in data" :key>
   <input :id="key" v-model="data[key]"/>
   <button @click="submitTest(value)"> testbtn </button>
 </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Vue.js, you should use `v-model` for two-way data binding. The `v-model` directive is a convenient shorthand for binding data to form inputs and updating the data on user input. However, it can't be directly used as a prop or passed as a parameter. Instead, you can pass the entire object and use it in the method.

Here's how you can modify your code:

```
<template>
  <div v-for="(item, idx) in data" :key="idx">
    <input :id="item" v-model="item.value"></input>
    <button @click="submitTest(item)">testbtn</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const data = ref([
  { id: 'input1', value: '' },
  { id: 'input2', value: '' },
  // ... other items
]);

function submitTest(item) {
  alert(item.value);
}
</script>
```

In this example, each item in the data array is an object with an `id` and `value` properties. The `v-model` directive is bound to `item.value`. When you click the button, the `submitTest` function is called with the entire item object, and you can access the value property from there.

Make sure to use `ref` to create a reactive reference to your data array in the setup script.

**Note**: `:key="idx"` is added to the `<div>` to provide a unique key for each item in the loop. This helps Vue.js efficiently update and re-render components when the array changes.

Comment: Actually I can access to v-model value just init like v-model="item", but thank you for answering and I solved the problem by referring to  the answer above! Have a nice day :)